# How should I configure VirtualBox to be able to connect to the internet from the guest OS

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am trying to move from VMware Fusion to VirtualBox since Fusion 3.0 is not working since I upgraded to Mountain Lion. VirtualBox is working but I cannot connect to the Internet on my guest OS (Windows XP). I am new to VirtualBox, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How have you configured the network interface?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Be sure that you have installed the latest version of Guest Additions to the VM
- Turn off the VM
- Under the network adapter configuration choose **bridged mode**
- Then click in advanced and change the adapter type to **Intel PRO/1000 MT Server (82545EM)**. -Be sure to enable the checkbox **"Cable Connected"**

Worked for me, hope it helps